# Equation $x^2+y^2=2y$ in spherical coordinates

Tags: spherical-coordinates

Write the equation $x^2+y^2=2y$ in spherical coordinates.

My solution: Using relation between spherical coordinates and rectangular we get:$$(\rho \cos \theta \sin \phi)^2+(\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi)^2=2\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi$$
$$\rho^2 \sin^2 \phi=2\rho \sin \theta \sin \phi$$

However the answer on the book is $\rho \sin \phi=2\sin \theta$. It look like mine but after reduction to $\rho \sin \phi$. Can anyone explain why we can reduce above equation to $\rho \sin \phi$? What about $\rho=0$ and $\phi=0,\pi$?

Would be very grateful for good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $\rho=0$ and $\sin \phi =0$ satisfy the equation, but the equation $\rho \sin \phi = 2 \sin \theta \ (*)$ includes the two conditions anyway.

$\rho = 0$ represents the point $(0,0,0)$,  which is obtained in $(*)$ by setting $\rho=0$, $\phi$ as any real number, and $\theta=0$.

$\sin\phi=0$ represents the z axis, which is obtained in $(*)$ by setting $\phi=k\pi$, $\rho$ as any real number, and $\theta=0$.

Comment: I think in your last sentence something is wrong. If we put in $(*)$ the $\phi=k\pi$ and $\theta=0$ we get $p\sin k\pi=\sin 0$ or $p\cdot 0=0$ ??!!

Comment: sorry I don't see the problem in that; $\rho \cdot 0$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $x^2+y^2=2y$ is same with $x^2+y^2-2y+1-1=0 \Leftrightarrow x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ it is more convenient to use little shift in polar coordinates:
$$x = r \cos \phi$$
$$y-1=r \sin \phi$$
Jakobian will not change, but equation becomes as easy as for usual circle $$r=1, \phi \in (0,2 \pi]$$.

For 3 dimension works same in spherical coordinates.